# How can I use list unpacking with condition in list?

Tags: python

This is what I'm attempting

`[1,2,3 if False else *[6,5,7]]`

This is what I'm expecting

`[1,2,3,6,5,7]`

How could I get this to work without flattening the list - i.e. `np.flatten([1,2,3 if False else [6,5,7]])` or similar

Is there an approach I can use to unpack `[6,5,7]` inside my list? Advice much appreciated!

Comment: With this `1,2,3 if False ...` - `1,2,3` should not go to the result, but you have it, why?

Comment: What list comprehension?

Comment: My bad, stackoverflowing on my commute :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unpack `[6, 5, 7]` or an empty list depending on a condition:

```
condition = False
data = [1, 2, 3, *([] if condition else [6, 5, 7])] 
# >>> [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 7]
```